# Dividing Akka source into batches

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I have a file parser, something like

```
def parser(file: File): Source[Record, NotUsed] = ...
```

and a function that consumes Records:

```
def send(source: Source[Record, _]: Future[Result]
```

The files are big, and the `send` function has a limit how many records it can stream at a time. So I need to split the file source into batches. I do it with a in-memory buffer:

```
parser(file)
  .grouped(batchSize)
  .mapAsync(2) { (batch: Seq[Record]) =>
    send(Source(batch))
  }
```

This works fine, but I it could be optimised if unbounded Source could be split into sub-Sources directly, without intermediate `Seq[Record]`.

Is there a way to do that? Something like

```
parser(file)
  .groupedToSources(batchSize)
  .mapAsync(2) { (batch: Source[Record, NotUsed]) =>
    send(batch)
  }
```

Essentially, I need an operator equivalent to

```
Flow[Record].grouped(batchSize).map(Source _)
```

but without an intermediate in-memory `Vector[Record]`